# Where do the electric field lines terminate inside a uniformly charged cubical surface?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, field-theory

The electric field inside a closed  uniform surface charge cannot be proven identically zero (except spherical). If the field inside is non-zero (say for a cubical surface), where do field lines terminate inside starting from the surface? Or can they escape out to infinity? I cannot picturise the field line scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do the electric field line terminate inside a uniformly charged cubical surface?

(Throughout, I am assuming electrostatic discipline).

Assuming a vacuum within the closed surface (i.e. no charges), the electric field is the gradient of a potential function satisfying Laplace's equation.

$$\nabla^2 V = 0$$

Thus $V$ is an harmonic function.

By the extremum theorem of harmonic functions, any potential found within the volume bounded by the surface will be found on the surface as well.

Without loss of generality, call the potential at the center of the cube $0$. That potential exists on the surface as well. Where can it exist? By symmetry, it might exist at the center of the six faces, at the center of each of 12 edges, or at the 8 vertices, or some combination of these sets. Lines of $0$ potential will then exist from the center to each of the points on the surface with $0$ potential.

> I cannot picturise the field line scenario.

Whichever lines those are, and at the moment, I am not sure which ones, the equipotential surfaces cannot intersect those lines without also being at $0$ potential. This may help you visualize the surfaces. I visualize the non-zero-potential equipotential surfaces as distorted hyperboloids (of two sheets) extending from the surface toward the center, but not touching the center. Perhaps with a little work I could give you a Fourier Series expansion.

> can they escape out to infinity?

All field lines that leave the surface toward the interior must return to the surface. These field lines then continue outside the cube and terminate at an opposite charge, or go on to infinity. However, they become significantly altered from passing through the surface charge. The intensity of the field, and its angle are both likely to change upon passing through the surface charge.

[This is not in your question, but it may be a stumbling block. Don't assume that the uniform surface charge entails a uniform potential on the surface. Also don't assume that a uniform surface charge is equivalent to the charge distribution on a conductive surface. I'm not saying you made these mistakes, but just in case... and also for the benefit of others who may struggle to understand this problem.]

Comment: 'All field lines that leave the surface toward the interior must return to the surface.'-- I am still in discomfort with this. The surface is not certainly equipotential. But still it is charged uniformly and field lines are supposed to either originate (for +ve charge) from the entire surface or terminate (for -ve charge) to the entire surface. So returning of field lines after emanating from it inside seems not viable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "originate/terminate from _entire_ surface. Lines originate at a points on the surface at particular potentials, and terminate at different points on the surface that are at different potentials.

Comment: As per convention, electric field lines originate from positive charges and terminate to negative charges. So if the surface charge density is positive everywhere, field lines would originate from the entire surface. What makes you tell they originate from an equipotential surface? Consider the simple situation of two equal but opposite charges placed at some distance. Here the perpendicular bisector plane of the line joining the two is an equipotential surface. The field lines originate from the +ve charge, crosses the said surface perpendicularly and ends at the -ve charge.

Comment: What I mean, there is nothing in electrostatics that states - ' Lines originate at a points on the surface at particular potentials, and terminate at different points on the surface that are at different potentials. ' Neither they necessarily meant to originate from nor meant to terminate to an equipotential surface. the only thing they are necessarily meant to is to cross the surface perpendicularly.

Comment: OK, I understand your concern. "Terminate" was a bad choice of words on my part. Field lines originate on the surface of the cube. Some are directed toward the interior. Those lines return to the surface of the cube, where they emerge from the cube and continue on to infinity or to an opposite charge. However, as they pass through the cube's surface, because of the surface charge, they do not emerge with the same field intensity, nor necessarily at the same angle.

Comment: Now here it repeats my concern that returning of those lines to the very surface violates the fact that it is a positively charged surface. It also violates the electric boundary condition (BC) across a surface charge. Any positively charged surface must have emerging field lines from both sides which ensures the BC of discontinuity of normal component of electric field.